# gedit plugin to highlight all instances of selection

Tags: gedit, plugins

Using gedit 3, I've tried multiple plugins to highlight all instances of the current selection (a la Notepad++):

https://code.google.com/p/smart-highlighting-gedit/

https://github.com/mmuell23/mmuell23

The smart-highlighting will seem to install and let me activate it, but doesn't seem to actually do anything.

The one at github was written for v2.  To try to hack it into v3, I've tried:

- change `.gedit-plugin` to just `.plugin`
- edit `IAge=2` to read `IAge=3`

That one still won't load (doesn't appear in `prefs->plugins` list).  Doesn't throw an error, just doesn't load.  I also can't find the gedit logs anywhere to see if there's a helpful message (I'm relatively new to Linux).  I checked `/var/logs/` but there's no gedit.

Can anyone help?  I just want the auto-highlighting to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any plugin to highlight all instances of a selection in gedit. Select the text about you are interested in, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (to search all instances of that selected text):

[image: gedit - highlight text]

---

Now, let me give you some explanations about those plugins. First one, `smart-highlighting` is working like a charm for me. How I made:

- First I checked my gedit version (from terminal with `gedit --version` command) - it's 3.6.2.
- Because my gedit version is 3.6.2, I downloaded [smart-highlighting-3.0.5.tar.gz](https://smart-highlighting-gedit.googlecode.com/files/smart-highlighting-3.0.5.tar.gz).
- Finally, I followed the [manually installation](https://code.google.com/p/smart-highlighting-gedit/wiki/Installation#Install_manually) method.

Second plugin, it's for gedit2.x and finish. It's not enough a simple hack like you tried.

### [UPDATE]

Only works if installed to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/`.  More in comments.

Comment: Thanks, but while that's true, it's not what I'm after.  I'm after the functionality as advertised in the referenced plugins.  I want to be able to select some text and have all matching instances be automatically highlighted.

Comment: Additionally, that highlighting (even as shown in your screenshot) is less useful as it takes a very lazy/naive approach and matches the "to" in "auto" as well as "to".

Comment: @Allen Yes, because there are searched strings, not words. Now, you said "instances", from my point of view in this case any string is an instance. You should edit your question and clarify these problems... automatically highlighted, highlight only words, etc.

Comment: @Allen See my new edits.

Comment: if you'd ever used Notepad++ on Windows, then my expectations would've been more...expected. :-)

Comment: also, my steps were exactly the same as the ones you listed.  It does install and allows me to enable the plugin, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Could you post a screenshot of what it looks like with the auto-highlighting working?

Comment: @Allen It's exactly like in the picture from here: https://code.google.com/p/smart-highlighting-gedit/. I suggest you to keep only one single plugin for this purpose and check again the versions... As I said, for me, it's working like a charm. I used [manually installation](https://code.google.com/p/smart-highlighting-gedit/wiki/Installation#Install_manually)

Comment: I also used the manual method.  Did you install globally or just for you?

Comment: @Allen Ah... I forgot to say this: just for me.

Comment: Installing for just me made it work.  I noticed a "_" vs. "-" difference in the naming of the config folder (which was initially empty), so I removed the plugin from my home dir to go test the global installation (which I hadn't removed yet).  But, even after closing and re-opening gedit, it still worked after removing the plugin from my home dir.  I noticed that the config dir (in home dir by default) is now populated.  Something weird about that, but I don't have time to investigate further.

Comment: You can search for complete words by right clicking the search box and selecting "Match Entire Word Only". (As a Notepad++ and gedit user, I think this "search to highlight" approach has some nice advantages and also some disadvantages. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 19.04, gedit 3.32 and gedit-plugins which have plugin "Quick highlight":

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

$ gedit --version
gedit - Version 3.32.0

sudo apt install gedit-plugins
```

and then manually enable it in Preferences - Plugins

[image: enable gedit plugin]

Answer (score -1):

This plugin does what you want, just follow the instructions in there: https://github.com/mmuell23/mmuell23

Comment: Please expand on your answer to include the directions referenced, as if the link ends up dead as a 404 the answer is of no use to anyone. If possible, try and reference the name of and instructions on how to install the plugin.

Comment: I think instructions themselves are useless without the actual plugin which is supposed to be available on the main site and not to be uploaded here. In addition, my instructions may become outdated after the author decides to change them anyhow.